# Call function from the same function

Tags: javascript

How can I call a function from the same function in angularjs?

Example:

```
function one(){

           function two(){
            //now I have to call function one()
           }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling it? Also, this has nothing to do with angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another function:

```
function one(){
       function two(){
            three();
         }
}


function three(){
    one();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code of reversing a string using recursion(function calling itself).

```
var str = 'NikhilMaheshwari';

function reverse(s) {
  return (s === '') ? '' : reverse(s.substr(1)) + s.charAt(0);
};

alert(reverse(str));
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/faqcuzen/